# Хороші питання і хороші відповіді / Good questions and good answers

Tags: discussion, faq, rules, quality-content, help-translated

> **Це запитання викликало суперечку стосовно змісту (content dispute).**
>   Пропозиції стосовно пунктів, які мають міститися в анонсі для новачків, обговорюються [у цьому запитанні](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/180/).

### Які питання вважаються хорошими

Більш докладно англійською мовою це описано [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) і [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Якщо коротко:

1. Намагайтеся ставити цікаві і корисні питання.
2. Подивіться на питання з точки зору потенційного читача. Як треба сформулювати питання, щоб воно було зрозуміле і корисне іншим? Пишіть чіткий заголовок і ясний текст, не гребуйте форматуванням і тегами.
3. Не дублюйте питання (скористуйтесь пошуком спочатку).
4. В цілому, вітаються питання зі «спробою дослідження». Ваше запитання не зобов'язане бути складним, у нас має бути комфортно як новачкам, так і тим, хто глибоко вивчає мову — але, у будь-якому випадку, поясніть, з якими саме проблемами ви стикнулись при спробі вирішити питання самотужки. Наприклад, «я бачу, що деякі словники пишуть „Арістотель“, а деякі — „Аристотель“, — чому так?», а не «як правильно: Арістотель чи Аристотель?».
5. Не пишіть питання, на які неможливо об'єктивно відповісти. (Цей сайт не для політичних міркувань, опитувань особистої думки і т.п.)

І звісно: питання мають стосуватися української мови. (Дозволені мови тексту: українська і англійська.) Будь-які питання технічного чи організаційного плану запитуйте в підрозділі «meta.ukrainian».

### Якими мають бути гарні відповіді

Більш докладно англійською мовою це описано [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/252301) і [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Якщо коротко:

1. Пишіть чітко (використовуйте форматування за потреби).
2. Аргументуйте вашу відповідь.
3. Якщо маєте посилання на джерела чи на додаткові подробиці — наведіть їх.
4. Не робіть лише посилання. (Навіть якщо за посиланням міститься повна і правильна відповідь — сформулюйте лаконічно своїми словами. Інакше сайт за посиланням може змінити адресу і читачі залишаться ні з чим.)
5. Намагайтеся подивитися на відповідь з точки зору читача (автора питання й інших). Що, по-вашому, слід зробити, щоби відповідь була точна, зрозуміла і повна? Зробіть це за потреби.

Не використовуйте відповіді просто для діалогу. Якщо треба щось уточнити в автора питання чи хочете написати щось корисне, що не є справжньою відповіддю — зробіть це в коментарі («add a comment»), а не у відповіді («Post Your Answer»).

### Про інші можливості

Система дозволяє редагувати («edit») питання і відповіді. Будь ласка, робіть це, якщо бачите якусь помилку чи вважаєте, що можете зробити ваше питання/відповідь кращою.

Ви можете також натискати «edit» на питаннях/відповідях інших користувачів. В такому разі редагування пройде лише якщо його узгодить автор чи інші люди. Використовуйте це лише для виправлення очевидних помилок, не робіть зміни, що не відповідають намірам оригінального автора.

Також, якщо ви автор питання, не забувайте ухвалити («✅») правильну/найкращу відповідь. І, в будь-якому разі, ви можете голосувати за/проти («⧍»/«⛛») чужі питання/відповіді і навіть голосувати за коментарі.

---

<sub>This text is a try to convey information to users, not a question — still you are allowed to express your thoughts, propositions, ideas within comments/answers.</sub>

### What questions are considered good

More detailed info in English is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

In short:

1. Try to ask interesting and useful questions.
2. Look onto the question from a potential reader's view. [Ask yourself:] How to phrase the question to make it understandable and useful for others? Write precise title and clear text, don't avoid formatting and tags.
3. Don't duplicate questions (use search first).
4. In general, questions with “research effort” are encouraged. Your question isn't obliged to be hard, as we are trying to make this site a comfortable place for everyone, starting from beginner learners up to the professional linguists — but in any case try to explain what specific problems you have faced with when trying to solve the problem by yourself. For example, [in short] “I see that some dictionaries write ‘Арістотель’, while others — ‘Аристотель’, — why [such divergence]?”, not “how to spell: Арістотель or Аристотель?”.
5. Don't write questions which you don't believe an abjective answer exist for. (This site is not a place for political thoughts, opinion surveys, etc.)

And of course: questions have to be about the Ukrainian language. (Allowed text languages are: Ukrainian and English.) Any technical and organizational questions are to be asked in the “meta.ukrainian” section.

### What nice answers are to be

More detailed info in English is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/252301) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

In short:

1. Write clear (use formatting when needed).
2. Argue your answer.
3. If you have references to sources or to more details — include them.
4. Don't make only links. (Even if a link points to full and correct answer — phrase it in short with your words. Otherwise readers will be disappointed, if a target site changes its address.)
5. Try to look onto the answer from reader's point of view (question author and others). [Ask yourself:] What in your opinion should be done to make the answer precise, understandable and full? Do so if needed.

Don't use answers for a dialog. If you need to ask details from question author or want to write something-useful-but-not-a-real-answer — do it in comments (“add a comment”), not in answers (“Post Your Answer”).

### About other possibilities

The system allows to edit (“edit”) questions and answers. Please do it if you see some mistake or you think that you can make your question/answer better.

Also you can press “edit” in questions/answers written by other users. In that case an edit will be applied only if the [original text] author or other people will approve it. Use it only for fixing apparent mistakes, don't apply edits that dramatically change the original author's intent.

Also, when you're a question author, don't forget to accept (“✅”) correct/best answer. And, in any case, you can vote up/down (“⧍”/“⛛”) others' questions/answers and even upvote the comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is announcement, not a real question.