# Яким може бути коментар до першого питання чи відповіді новачка?

Tags: discussion, admin-reference, participation, comments

Яким може бути текст коментаря до першого питання чи відповіді новачка, якщо, на вашу думку, вона не відповідає вимогам нашого сайту?

Answer (score 2):

## How They Do It:

- Mi Yodeya.SE [has some templates](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/welcoming-new-users)
- [Auto-Moderating tool](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) at StackApps
- Meta.SE discussions: [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162021/templates-for-moderators-for-comments), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74088/template-comments-for-the-regular-raise-accept-rate-format-code-etc)
- [A Search query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcomments%5D+template) for more Meta.SE dicsussions

---

## How We Do It

Мені здається, що шаблонна відповідь — це не найкраще рішення.

Та й недоліки у кожному випадку — різні…

Не те, щоб я був *категорично* проти, але ми ж не роботи якісь. Кожен сам собі може вести якісь шаблони, це невід'ємне право. Але «фіксувати» — це, НМД, виглядає way too formal.

---

Окремо від цього, варто нагадати типові шаблони для пришвидшення написання коментарів.

[Comment Formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Особливо, це стосується `[edit]`, `[meta]`, `[ask]`, `[answer]` тощо.

Там не вистачає таких фічей, як лінк на конкретне запитання (наприклад, неможливо коротко написати лінк на відоме [Хороші питання і хороші відповіді / Good questions and good answers](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/)
(мені не вдалися варіанти виду `//[meta]/q/5`)

Comment: Я спочатку неуважно прочитав текст Nash Bridges, замість «зафіксувати» прочитав «запропонувати» (навіть не як «recommend», а «suggest»). В такому варіанті — ОК, як на мене. Тілько б я писав код у вікі-відповіді, а не в самому питання, щоб інші могли редагувати.

Answer (score 2):

Коментар може (але **не мусить**) виглядати так:

#### Коментар до відповіді

`Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші відповіді. Цей допис не відповідає таким критеріям: ... Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, надавши більш аргументовану відповідь. Для цього натисніть [edit].`

#### Коментар до питання

`Вітаємо на сайті Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. (описати як можна покращити допис) Ви завжди можете виправити свій допис за допомогою посилання [edit].`