# How our announcement for the new users should look like? Яким має бути наш анонс для новачків?

Tags: discussion, rules, help-translated, participation

Most StackExchange sites have announcements for new users.

There is also [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), where each list item refers a relevant question on Meta.SE

The problem is, the list is quite big and it is in English which may be difficult for new users who may not comprehend English very well.

There was an [announcement here at Meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/) which was posted as question and raised a discussion about its content.

**What topics should our announcement include?**

---

Більшість сайтів StackExchange містять анонс для новачків.

Також, є великий [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), де кожний пункт списку є посиланням на відповідне запитання на Meta.SE

Проблема полягає у тому, що той список є досить великим, а також те, що він написаний англійською, що може бути проблемою для новачків, хто не занадто добре володіє англійською.

Раніше був [анонс на нашій Meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/), який був опублікований як запитання і викликав дискусію стосовно того, який вміст там має бути.

**Отже, які пункти мають бути у нашому анонсі для новачків?**

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be closed by [that](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/181/4) answer. We don't need help pages in Meta too much, because we can translate [our help itself](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/).

The first things we should translate are:

- [How do I ask a good question?](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How do I write a good answer?](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Me may also provide some additional information (that wouldn't be a direct translation of [the global Stack Exchange help](//meta.stackexchange.com/help)): either by creating additional pages within our help (if it is technically possible), or by modifying texts of some of our help pages making them not-just-a-direct-translation of the common Stack Exchange help (if it is allowed by Stack Exchange rules), or by creating special pages in the Meta (if neither of other ways is possible). But this certainly isn't our first priority:

- We shouldn't invent our own policy/help pages until we translate the global ones.
- IMHO, we should not do it at all until our community becomes large and stable enough. Any decisions done now would be decisions of several active members, not of the real community.

Comment: I would say we should focus on writing up some content for `on-topic` page first. Translating `how-to-ask` and `how-to-answer` may take longer as it would require: (1) consensus on format; (2) consensus on content; (3) request for SE developers to intrude. The rest of this answer looks fine.

Comment: @bytebuster, what consensus on format and content are you talking about? Let's just do a literal translation. And what request for SE developers are you talking about? You've said you have edit buttons as moderator. On the other hand, we **can't** fill "[on-topic](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" because it really **requires** consensus.

Comment: (1) Literal translation — agreed. (2) Consensus on format (to avoid further content disputes) — all translations require such consensus. (3) I have edit buttons for **only few** pages. The rest require intrusion of site developers.