# Коментар vs відповідь

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

Можна відреагувати на запитання, давши коментар і давши відповідь.

Якщо я правильно розумію,  
**коментар** призначений для уточнення запитання (побажань кращого формулювання, сумнівів у доцільності, дуже дрібних і невизначених порад у пошуках відповіді деінде), 
а **відповідь** призначена для власне відповіді по суті.

а) чи правильно я проводжу межу і де вона, якщо ні? 
б) чому деякі користувачі *відповідають* на запитання коментарем?  
в) якщо користувач соромиться створювати відповідь і обмежується коментарем, то як це побороти?  
г) якщо є автоматичне перетворення короткої відповіді на коментар, то чи можна це вимкнути? 
д) чи можна перетворити уже доданий коментар на відповідь?

Answer (score 6):

> а) чи правильно я проводжу межу і де вона, якщо ні?

Так, саме таким чином у інтерфейсі сайту пояснюється різниця між коментарем та відповіддю. Проте, відповідь повинна бути якісною, про критерії якості можна почитати [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/69). Коментарі вважаються тимчасовими і потенційно можуть одного дня зникнути, тому важливу інформацію краще переносити у відповіді або у запитання.

> б) чому деякі користувачі відповідають на запитання коментарем?

Тут може бути декілька причин - від невпевненості від того що справді потрібно тому, хто поставив питання, до нестачі часу на формулювання якісної відповіді.

> в) якщо користувач соромиться створювати відповідь і обмежується коментарем, то як це побороти?

Нагадувати, що коментарі з часом можуть загубитися, а за хорошу відповідь можна отримати бали репутації (за коментар репутацію отримати неможливо). До того ж 1 голос за відповідь дає 10 очок, голос проти відбирає 2 очки; 1 голос за питання дає 5 очок (отже, давати відповіді вигідніше, ніж ставити питання). Також новачкам за більш-менш хорошу відповідь завжди дають пару голосів.

> г) якщо є автоматичне перетворення короткої відповіді на коментар, то чи можна це вимкнути?

Наскільки мені відомо, автоматичного механізму немає. Швидше за все, таку конвертацію зробив модератор. (Взагалі, модератору в такому разі було б варто залишити коментар про причину такої дії).

Такою причиною зазвичай є те, що відповідь коротка та не відповідає критеріям якісної відповіді, наприклад - висловлюється власна думка без посилань на поважні джерела (тобто це відповідь-репліка у стилі розмови, фактично коментар).

> д) чи можна перетворити уже доданий коментар на відповідь?

Ви завжди можете скопіювати текст коментаря і вставити його в нову відповідь. (Наприклад, коли ви відповіли коментарем, а потім вирішили зробити це відповіддю). Тільки впевніться, що така відповідь буде відповідати критеріям якісної відповіді.

Comment: «Наскільки мені відомо, автоматичного механізму немає.» — 100%, що є, принаймні в ме́ті. Я сам через це страждав [отут](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/83). Обійшов штучним доданням непотрібного тексту в кінці відповіді. (Потім цей текст можна було прибрати, відредагувавни відповідь. Чомусь я про це не подумав.)

Answer (score 1):

Більшість аспектів освітлено у чудовій відповіді @Artemix. Я лише додам, що на багатьох сайтах Stack Exchange виникає ця проблема. Ось це [запитання](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533) на RPG.SE і [відповідь](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534) на нього варта перепосту цілком.

#### Короткий переказ

Відповіді у коментарях руйнують результат багаторічних спроб-і-помилок, завдяки яким спільнота Stack Exchange виробила механізми відділення «добра і зла», хорошого контенту від поганого, а також механізмів співпраці багатьох користувачів, чиї індивідуальні цілі і уподобання можуть значно відрізнятися одні від одних.
Але завдяки цим механізмам, учасники можуть ефективно створювати якісний контент.
Це — найголовніше, бо це є фундаментальною метою Stack Exchange.

У деталях, (напів-)відповіді у коментарях:

- можна надавати до закритих (closed) запитань — іншими словами, вони ігнорують факт закриття (неякісного) запитання спільнотою, а значить, не спонукають автора створювати інше, *якісне* запитання;
- неможливо позначати Accepted Answer;
- провокують на довгі дебати, де коментарями відповідають на коментарі, і швидко втрачається контекст;
- коментарі під запитанням по-шахрайськи знаходяться вище, ніж будь-які — навіть найбільш upvoted — відповіді на запитання;
- вони не піддаються типовим захисним механізмам: їх неможливо downvote, відредагувати, запитати про уточнення, тощо.

#### Підсумок:

Голосування/закриття/видалення є частиною стандартної функціональності сайту.
Контент, що не відповідає нашим критеріям якості, отримує голоси униз чи на видалення.
Відповіді-через-коментар не піддаються стандартній системі контролю спільноти за контентом.

#### Оригінальний текст

> You should not answer in comments. Not partial answers, not full answers. Not "leads on" an answer. Not "I would answer but I'm tired/just woke up/am drunk so I'll just say this..." These will be deleted. Answer in answers.
>
> Answering in comments does the following things.
>
> 1. It bypasses question closes. They're closed for a reason.
> 2. It provides an answer that can't be marked as an answer for future people's knowledge.
> 3. It contributes to long comment debates as you can comment on an answer, but it's unclear what you're commenting on in a comment thread.
> 4. It is "cheating" by locking your answer to the top. Answers with higher votes/accepted answers should go to the top to indicate their quality. Bypassing that by sticking your answer in a comment on the question is unacceptable.
> 5. It bypasses all our quality control mechanisms: we can't downvote your "answer", edit it, or comment on it to request clarification or improvements. Answers also bump a question to the top so that people will scrutinize the answer; comments don't do this.
>
> The long and short of it is, every part of how how the site functions, all of which have lengthy justification as being part of the process of SE - rep, answers, accepts, edits, etc - is obviated by using comments for answers. So every good goal of all that functionality is nullified by this practice.
>
> Now, "but the hapless questioner could use that info!" In nearly all cases someone posts the same information in a (much more comprehensive) answer. Or take the time yourself to write a real answer. We don't like crappy questions or crappy answers, and we'd rather not have the Q or A than to have one that doesn't meet site quality (hence closes/deletes, part of the standard SE functionality). If you don't care enough to write a real answer don't, the likelihood that you're the only person in the world/on the site that knows that bit of info is very small.
>
> While users are welcome to steal the info in the comments to generate answers of their own, that will not slow the pace of dealing with the answers-in-comments via flagging and deletion.